# Convergence of fixed-point iterations for a nonsmooth mapping

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I have a compact convex domain $\mathcal{D} \subset R_{0+}^{n}$ (nonnegative vectors in $R^n$),
and a mapping $f:\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}$.

The function $f$ is continuous, but nonsmooth ($f$ is a piecewise linear nondecreasing concave function over $\mathcal{D}$)

Because of continuity of $f$ and a compact-convex $\mathcal{D}$, we know by Brouwer fixed-point theorem that there exists atleast one $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\bar{x}=f(\bar{x})$ (Existence of fixed-point).

Now, I am trying to show that the iterations $x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})$ converge to some fixed-point $\tilde{x} \in \mathcal{D}$, i.e., to some point satisfying $\tilde{x}=f(\tilde{x})$, for any initial-condition $x_0 \in \mathcal{D}$.

One fact I know is that there exists a matrix $M \in R^{n \times n}$, such that for all $x \in \mathcal{D}$, the component-wise inequality
$f(x) \leq Mx$ holds.

The properties of matrix $M$ are as follows:

1. Each component $M_{ij} \geq 0, i=1,..,n, j=1,..n$.
2. $\rho(M)<1$ (Largest absolute value of the eigen values of $M$ is less than 1)

Is there any way to show that the iterations $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ converge to some fixed-point in $\mathcal{D}$ from any initial-condition $x_0 \in \mathcal{D}$?

I intuitively see that the iterations $x_+=f(x)$ are always upper-bounded by the iterations of the decaying linear system $x_+=Mx$ (since $\rho(M)<1$).
However, I am unable to use this matrix to establish convergence.

Very grateful for your time.

Comment: Is the application contracting ? I.e. for some norm, is $\|x_{k+1}-x_\infty\|\le\lambda\|x_k-x_\infty\|$ and $\lambda<1$ ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am precisely unable to relate the existence of the upper-bounding stable matrix $M$ to the existence of some contracting factor $\lambda <1$.

Comment: Either there is a relation between $\rho$ and $\lambda$, or there is none. Sorry, this is all I can tell you. Except that by induction $x_n\le M^n x_0$ and the RHS vanishes.